# mongodb query referenced objects inside array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose in nodejs. I'm trying to query some fields that contains a list made of referenced objects. I created two schemas

**PILOT**

```
var PilotSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    races: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Race'}],
});
```

**RACE**

```
var RaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    start_ms: Number,
});
```

Here I wrote only the relevant fields.

In the race schema I have a key `start_ms` that indicates the date of the start of the race in millisecons, and in the PilotSchema `races` field I save the references to many races.

What I want to do is:

- Take a date in the future ( my_date ) in milliseconds
- Retrive all the pilots that have not a race in the interval (my_date - 2_hours, my_date + 2_hours)

I try to do an example for explain better.

My date: Feb 23 2020 - 12:00:00 ( in milliseconds ),

In the pilot field `races` I have many refences to  the `RaceSchema` and in each refenced object ther is the time of the start of a race.

Now querying the Pilots collection I want to retrieve all the pilots that in they `races` field have not a race that start during (`Feb 23 2020 - 10:00:00 - Feb 23 2020 - 14:00:00`)

I tried using this query but didn't work

```
races: {$not:
  {$elemMatch: 
    {start_ms: 
      { "$gt" : min_time, "$lt" : max_time }
    }
  }
}
```

Where

```
min_time, max_time = my_date - 2_hours, my_date + 2_hours
```

Actually I don't know how to do it, I saw that for retrive a number in an intervall I can use `$gt` and `$lt` but I don't understand how to query an array of referenced objects that respect this specific conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write an aggregate query for this, finding your reference of `races` from `pilot` & filter them based on your condition

```
 Pilot.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup:{
                    from:'races',
                    localField:'races',
                    foreignField:'_id',
                    as:'races'
                }
            },{
                $unwind:'$races'
            },
            {
                $match:{
                    'races.start_ms':{
                        "$gt" : min_time, "$lt" : max_time
                    }
                }
            },{
                $group:{
                    _id:'$_id',
                    name:{$first:'$name'}
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Assuming that you have `name` in your `pilot` schema, you can get list of all such `pilots` by writing this query